# How to get the string before .(dot) and after /(last) slash in Java

Tags: java

I have a string like this:

```
"core/pages/viewemployee.jsff"
```

From this code, I need to get "viewemployee". How do I get this using Java?

Comment: [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

Comment: This seems like a valid question, why the down votes?

Comment: @user3560827 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 24):

Suppose that you have that string saved in a variable named `myString`.

```
String myString = "core/pages/viewemployee.jsff";
String newString = myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("/")+1, myString.indexOf("."));
```

But you need to make the same control before doing `substring` in this one, because if there aren't those characters you will get a "-1" from `lastIndexOf()`, or `indexOf()`, and it will break your `substring` invocation.

I suggest looking for [the Javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Answer (score 21):

You can solve this with regex (given you only need a group of word characters between the last "/" and "."):

```
    String str="core/pages/viewemployee.jsff";
    str=str.replaceFirst(".*/(\\w+).*","$1");
    System.out.println(str); //prints viewemployee
```

Comment: You need to go through a regex tutorial. The comments field is too little to explain everything. The first part, i.e. ".*/" matches everything until the last /, then comes grouping (\\W+)  which means a at least one word-character then it stops at . because dot is not a word character. The last part again .* means everything. In the replacement part I just refer to the group by its number $1. Since there is one group (\\w+) I use $1. Here is the regex api for java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: This will fail on e.g. "foo.exe" (no slash) and "/foo/bar.baz.exe" (two dots).

Comment: ...and "/2014-05-23.log" (or anything else with punctuation in the file name)

Comment: The answer is to the given example in the question. For numeric and other types of values, you will need to use appropriate character class.

Answer (score 8):

You can split the string first with "/" so that you can have each folder and the file name got separated. For this example, you will have "core", "pages" and "viewemployee.jsff". I assume you need the file name without the extension, so just apply same split action with "." seperator to the last token. You will have filename without extension.

```
String myStr = "core/pages/viewemployee.bak.jsff";

String[] tokens = myStr.split("/");
String[] fileNameTokens = tokens[tokens.length - 1].split("\\.");

String fileNameStr = "";

for(int i = 0; i < fileNameTokens.length - 1; i++) {
    fileNameStr += fileNameTokens[i] + ".";
}

fileNameStr = fileNameStr.substring(0, fileNameStr.length() - 1);

System.out.print(fileNameStr) //--> "viewemployee.bak"
```

Comment: The regex will only return the first segment for filenames with more than one dot, e.g. "core/pages/viewemployee.jsff.bak".

Comment: You're right but even if that is the case, by this code he gets the filename without the extension. Even if that file is a backup file, he will still get the filename, "viewemployee", which he desires to get.

Comment: Well, typically, at least for program associations, the extension is whatever follows the last dot, not the first. And outside of those there really isn't a concept of extension as far as most filesystems are concerned. But I'll grant you that it's not really clear what the OP wants.

Comment: @johncip This answer got upvoted so I came in and saw that you are right, my answer should be updated.

Answer (score 8):

These are file paths. Consider using File.getName(), especially if you already have the File object:

```
File file = new File("core/pages/viewemployee.jsff");
String name = file.getName(); // --> "viewemployee.jsff"
```

And to remove the extension:

```
String res = name.split("\\.[^\\.]*$")[0]; // --> "viewemployee"
```

With this we can handle strings like `"../viewemployee.2.jsff"`.

The regex matches the last dot, zero or more non-dots, and the end of the string. Then String.split() treats these as a delimiter, and ignores them. The array will always have one element, unless the original string is `.`.

Answer (score 6):

The below will get you **viewemployee.jsff**:

```
int idx = fileName.replaceAll("\\", "/").lastIndexOf("/");
String fileNameWithExtn = idx >= 0 ? fileName.substring(idx + 1) : fileName;
```

To remove the file Extension and get only **viewemployee**, similarly:

```
idx = fileNameWithExtn.lastIndexOf(".");
String filename = idx >= 0 ? fileNameWithExtn.substring(0,idx) : fileNameWithExtn;
```